# What is the reason to keep all Django models and views in single files?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

What is the reason to keep many views in 1 views.py file?
Why it is not easier to create:

```
views/
    __init__.py
    view1.py
    ...
```

The same is for models.

Comment: You don't keep *all* your views in a single module, just ones specific to that app. If you have to segment it that way, it probably makes sense to separate the app into multiple apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separating Django App Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696318/separating-django-app-views)